postfix doesnt deliver nor receive mails
I set up a docker container (mailserver/docker-mailserver) on my server.
Postfix is giving me the following log when I try to send or receive a mail:
2024-07-30T17:40:01.753276+02:00 mail postfix/qmgr[3154]: 9DBBF957B: from=<mymail@mydomain.com>, size=600, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
2024-07-30T17:40:01.764623+02:00 mail postfix/error[7220]: 9DBBF957B: to=<mymail@mydomain.com>, relay=none, delay=0.13, delays=0.12/0/0/0.01, dsn=4.7.0, status=deferred (message is administratively expired)
2024-07-30T17:40:01.764755+02:00 mail postfix/qmgr[3154]: 9DBBF957B: from=<mymail@mydomain.com>, status=force-expired, returned to sender
2024-07-30T17:40:01.770310+02:00 mail postfix/cleanup[7222]: BBEB49797: message-id=<20240730154001.BBEB49797@mail.mydomain.com>
2024-07-30T17:40:01.779375+02:00 mail postfix/bounce[7221]: 9DBBF957B: sender non-delivery notification: BBEB49797
2024-07-30T17:40:01.779648+02:00 mail postfix/qmgr[3154]: BBEB49797: from=<>, size=3105, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
2024-07-30T17:40:01.779913+02:00 mail postfix/qmgr[3154]: 9DBBF957B: removed
2024-07-30T17:40:01.783278+02:00 mail postfix/error[7220]: BBEB49797: to=<mymail@mydomain.com>, relay=none, delay=0.02, delays=0.01/0/0/0, dsn=4.7.0, status=deferred (message is administratively expired)
2024-07-30T17:40:01.783427+02:00 mail postfix/qmgr[3154]: BBEB49797: from=<>, status=force-expired, returned to sender
2024-07-30T17:40:01.783832+02:00 mail postfix/qmgr[3154]: BBEB49797: removed

for testing I sent a mail from my created mail-adress to itself.
The same happens when sending to my private gmail or from my private gmail.
I swapped my actual domain and mail-adress for placeholder variables.
I cannot figure out why the emails are being blocked.
postconf -n reports the following:
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
compatibility_level = 3.6
content_filter = smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
disable_vrfy_command = yes
dkim_milter = inet:localhost:8891
dmarc_milter = inet:localhost:8893
dms_smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_unknown_sender_domain
header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/maps/header_checks.pcre
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
message_size_limit = 10240000
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 6
mua_sender_restrictions = $dms_smtpd_sender_restrictions
mydestination = localhost, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
mydomain = mydomain.com
myhostname = mail.mydomain.com
mynetworks =
non_smtpd_milters = $dkim_milter
policyd-spf_time_limit = 3600
postscreen_bare_newline_action = enforce
postscreen_dnsbl_action = ignore
postscreen_dnsbl_allowlist_threshold = -1
postscreen_dnsbl_sites =
postscreen_dnsbl_threshold = 3
postscreen_greet_action = enforce
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/maps/sender_header_filter.pcre
smtp_tls_CApath = /etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_loglevel = 1
smtp_tls_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3,!TLSv1,!TLSv1.1
smtp_tls_security_level = none
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_data_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_pipelining
smtpd_delay_reject = yes
smtpd_discard_ehlo_keywords = silent-discard, dsn
smtpd_forbid_bare_newline = yes
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_invalid_helo_hostname, permit
smtpd_milters = $dkim_milter $dmarc_milter
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination, check_policy_service unix:private/policyd-spf, reject_invalid_helo_hostname, reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, check_policy_service inet:localhost:65265
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = no
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $mydomain
smtpd_sasl_path = /dev/shm/sasl-auth.sock
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sender_restrictions = $dms_smtpd_sender_restrictions
smtpd_tls_CApath = /etc/ssl/certs
smtpd_tls_chain_files = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_dh1024_param_file = /etc/postfix/dhparams.pem
smtpd_tls_exclude_ciphers = aNULL, SEED, CAMELLIA, RSA+AES, SHA1
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = high
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3,!TLSv1,!TLSv1.1
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3,!TLSv1,!TLSv1.1
smtpd_tls_security_level = none
smtputf8_enable = no
tls_high_cipherlist = ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
tls_preempt_cipherlist = yes
tls_ssl_options = NO_COMPRESSION, NO_RENEGOTIATION
virtual_alias_maps = texthash:/etc/postfix/virtual
virtual_mailbox_domains = /etc/postfix/vhost
virtual_mailbox_limit = 0
virtual_mailbox_maps = texthash:/etc/postfix/vmailbox
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:/var/run/dovecot/lmtp

postconf -M reports:
smtp       inet  n       -       n       -       1       postscreen
smtpd      pass  -       -       n       -       -       smtpd
tlsproxy   unix  -       -       n       -       0       tlsproxy
dnsblog    unix  -       -       n       -       0       dnsblog
submission inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd -o syslog_name=postfix/submission -o smtpd_tls_security_level=none -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no -o smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header=yes -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions -o smtpd_discard_ehlo_keywords= -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING -o cleanup_service_name=sender-cleanup
submissions inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd -o syslog_name=postfix/submissions -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=no -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no -o smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header=yes -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions -o smtpd_discard_ehlo_keywords= -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING -o cleanup_service_name=sender-cleanup
pickup     fifo  n       -       n       60      1       pickup -o content_filter= -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks
sender-cleanup unix n    -       n       -       0       cleanup -o syslog_name=postfix/sender-cleanup -o header_checks=pcre:/etc/postfix/maps/sender_header_filter.pcre
cleanup    unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
qmgr       unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr     unix  -       -       n       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite    unix  -       -       n       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
defer      unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
trace      unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
verify     unix  -       -       n       -       1       verify
flush      unix  n       -       n       1000?   0       flush
proxymap   unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix  -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp       unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
relay      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
showq      unix  n       -       n       -       -       showq
error      unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
retry      unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
discard    unix  -       -       n       -       -       discard
local      unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual    unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp       unix  -       -       n       -       -       lmtp
anvil      unix  -       -       n       -       1       anvil
scache     unix  -       -       n       -       1       scache
postlog    unix-dgram n  -       n       -       1       postlogd
policyd-spf unix -       n       n       -       0       spawn user=policyd-spf argv=/usr/bin/policyd-spf
smtp-amavis unix -       -       n       -       2       smtp -o syslog_name=postfix/$service_name -o smtp_data_done_timeout=1200 -o smtp_send_xforward_command=yes -o disable_dns_lookups=yes -o max_use=20 -o smtp_tls_security_level=none -o smtp_tls_wrappermode=no
127.0.0.1:10025 inet n   -       n       -       -       smtpd -o syslog_name=postfix/smtpd-amavis -o content_filter= -o local_recipient_maps= -o relay_recipient_maps= -o smtpd_restriction_classes= -o smtpd_delay_reject=no -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject -o smtpd_helo_restrictions= -o smtpd_sender_restrictions= -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject -o smtpd_data_restrictions=reject_unauth_pipelining -o smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions= -o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8 -o smtpd_error_sleep_time=0 -o smtpd_soft_error_limit=1001 -o smtpd_hard_error_limit=1000 -o smtpd_client_connection_count_limit=0 -o smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit=0 -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks,no_unknown_recipient_checks,no_milters -o smtp_tls_security_level=none

I have port forwarded the following Ports: 25, 143, 465, 587, 993
for network setting I have set the following:
hostname: mail
domain name: mydomain.com

additionally I have added the capabilities:
NET_ADMIN
SYS_PTRACE

The following Volumes are bound:
Volumes bound to the docker container
Verbose Logging:
https://gist.github.com/JustLokust/af197ba4617f551f7665c35d88a4c079

How is your email server configured?

Also, these messages were long time in queue. We only see their eventual death, which says nothing about why they were destined to death. How they entered the mail system? That event is likely to be around a week before. Grep your mail logs for 9DBBF957B and BBEB49797.

@NikitaKipriyanov  I actually setup the email server only today, so no, the emails are certainly not a week old. Actually I sent them out and it took them barely a second to be logged. I also did a "docker exec -it mailserver mailq" and it reported that 0 mails were in the queue.

@symcbean I will edit the post with further information

Sorry, we don't care about your docker variables. We are interested in your Postfix configuration files, main.cf and master.cf, and more, instead of posting them raw, use postconf -n and postconf -M to produce their filtered and relevant form. Also, our suggestions will be probably concerned about modifying these files, and it's your problem to find out how to do it in dockerized Postfix. (Otherwise, it's very close to "web administration panels" to me, which "makes normal administration methods ineffective" and is off topic for that.)

@NikitaKipriyanov Sorry I am not very fond of how things are handled on StackExchange. I added the postconf reports in the post.

Well, it's -M, not -m is used to tell the contents of master.cf. Well, your mydomain.com is not in mydestination, and your virtual_*_domains refers to the sidecar file, /etc/postfix/vhost, and virtual_*_maps also refers to the sidecar files. Is that domain and email in these sidecar files? There is a policy service on port 65265 (invoked by smtpd_recipient_restrictions), what is it and what is it doing, does it have a log?

@NikitaKipriyanov mydomain.com is indeed included in /etc/postfix/vhost.
/etc/postfix/vmailbox contains my email and domain in the following style: mymail@mydomain.com mydomain.com/mymail/.
I checked Port 65265 with ss -lptn and it reports that dovecot is listening on it.

Well, "can't tell". Can you collect more verbose logs? For that, you add the test client's IP address to debug_peer_list parameter in main.cf, reload and send a test email. It will log a lot about the processing of that transaction, including the inputs to every test in every restriction list and the outcome. We'll able to tell on what stage it does something unexpected.

@NikitaKipriyanov I added alink to a github gist that includes my verbose logging, since it was too long to include in the post. Thank you for your help.
